# Getting NoneType in my python selenium despite .text method used

Tags: python, selenium, web-crawler, nonetype

I'm trying to workout the number of for loops to run depending on the number of List (totalListNum)

And it seems that it is returning Nonetype when infact it should be returning either text or int[image: Here]

website:https://stamprally.org/?search_keywords=&search_keywords_operator=and&search_cat1=68&search_cat2=0

Code Below

```
for prefectureValue in prefectureValueStorage:
    driver.get(
        f"https://stamprally.org/?search_keywords&search_keywords_operator=and&search_cat1={prefectureValue}&search_cat2=0")
    # Calculate How Many Times To Run Page Loop
    totalListNum = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(
        'div.page_navi2.clearfix>p').get_attribute('text')
    totalListNum.text.split("件中")
    if totalListNum[0] % 10 != 0:
        pageLoopCount = math.ceil(totalListNum[0])
    else:
        continue
    currentpage = 0
    while currentpage < pageLoopCount:
        currentpage += 1
        print(currentpage)
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you should use get_attribute. Instead try this.

```
totalListNum = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div.page_navi2.clearfix>p').text
```

Answer (score 0):

First, your locator is not unique
Use this:

```
div.page_navi2.clearfix:nth-of-type(1)>p
```

or for the second element:

```
div.page_navi2.clearfix:nth-of-type(2)>p
```

Second, as already mentioned, use `.text` to get the text.

Answer (score 0):

If .text does not work you can use .get_attribute('innerHTML')